# useEffect with time interval runs twice each time

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Hello I have a simple application where I fetch data every 3 seconds by using useEffect with time interval. Everything works as needed buy by logging in the console I see that my useEffect works twice, it calls fetchData function twice almost at the same time. I think I am missing something in my code. Thank you for your help!

```
       useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          fetchChatData();
        }, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      });

  const fetchChatData = () => {
    setError(null);

    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(
        "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/60e6d8a81f8e4a7f2a",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Master-Key":
              "$2b$10$OSaM64SeFaeWQMwrro08kuypgEG7Q",
          },
        }
      );
      const responseData = await request.data;
      chatCtx.setChatData(responseData.record);
    }

    fetchData();
    fetchData().catch((error) => {
      setError(error.response.data.message);
    });
  };
```

Comment: if your interval is stored with `useState`, then it is expected. Invoking `setInterval` in `useEffect` will cause redraw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling fetchData function twice out of useEffect that causes the second API call.

Remove

```
fetchData();
```

before

```
fetchData().catch((error) => {
      setError(error.response.data.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 hooks. The first hook executes when the component loads and therefore it's dependency array is set to an empty array `[]`

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // invoke web service to read data into the chatData state variable 
   // when the component loads for the first time
},[])
```

Then I have another `useEffect` hook that has the `chatData` state variable set into it's dependency array. This hook will wait for 3-seconds before invoking the web service.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // wait 3 seconds
   // invoke web service to read data into the chatData state variable
},[chatData])
```

Each time the web service is invoked in the 2nd hook, the `chatData` dependency in the hook will change and this in turn will cause this hook to fire again indefinitely.

Comment: The approach is good. but he just need to remove that extra fetchData inside fetchData.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all your component's code but an `useEffect` as is runs on every component's re-render. Juat ad an empty array as `useEffect`'s second parameter and it will run just first component's render. Something like:

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          fetchChatData();
        }, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, []);
```